# How to  Change phone type programmatically?

Tags: android, telephony

In my app I want to change the phone type (GSM/CMDA).
`getPhoneType()` method in TelephonyManager

```
returns 1 (PHONE_TYPE_GSM) 
or 2 (PHONE_TYPE_CDMA).
```

I can change this manually through phone

```
menu - Networks - Mobile Networks - Network Type ()
AUTO/GSM/CDMA.
```

Can I change this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In [`Settings.Secure`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html), you have `NETWORK_PREFERENCE` which is described as:

> User preference for which network(s) should be used. Only the connectivity service should touch this.

This leads you to [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) which looks like it is only for data connection, so all the above information really is useless, but good to be aware of.

And in [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) There is no `set` method, so the only thing that may work is if you look at [internal and hidden methods](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).